# Submit Button on InfoPath

Tags: infopath

Does anyone know if a 'submit button' in infopath can be progammed to email and update a sharepoint list at the same time?
Thanks.

Comment: We need more information to answer your question. Please edit  your post and add details as requested by the folks who are trying to answer your question. See our [FAQ](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) for general guidelines.

Comment: In my experience the email functionality is only available for a "forms" library, not a list.

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know if a 'submit button' in infopath can be progammed to
>   email and update a sharepoint list at the same time? Thanks

Me. I know.

A 'submit button' can certainly be programmed to email and update. But how to do it depends on many unspecified in question details:

- is Infopath 2003? 2010?,
- which type/compatibility of template?

  - Sharepoint List Form?
  - Workflow Form?
  - Web Browser Form (and it it is web enabled one)
  - Filler
- published to/stored where

  - sharepoint form library?
  - network share?
  - on client machine?
- etc., etc.

So, it does not have a concrete answer in its currently undefined context, i.e. it is a guessing game. From the other side, the concrete answers are multiple variants per each concrete possible (known only to topic starter) context and are   available by search on internet.

**Update (answer to comment):**

> I have Infopath 2010. I created the form from a sharepoint list and
>   want it to publish/store to the same sharepoint list (not library -
>   that option is available on infopath). I'm not sure if I answered
>   everything??

No, your comment does not answer how you created the Infopath form, with which options, data connections and options of fata connections (what is its compatibility and how you connected a sharepoint list to it).

It is a guessing game with distorted initial data.

For example, if I create Infopath 2010 form (by pressing **Customize Form** button on ribbon in browser) of **Sharepoint List Form** type (in Infopath Designer 2010, File > Info > Form Options > Compatibility ? Form Type:),

[image]

I see that it has options to submit to its sharepoint list (in Infoapth Designer 2010, File > Info > Submit Options button):

[image: Submit options of Sharepoint List Form Infopath 2010 form]

as well as it has clear instructions how to do it if you wish to choose submission it to more than one/single location, for example. both to email and sharepoint list:

- Perform Custom actions using Rules
  To set rules that will run when a user submits the form, on the Data tab, in the Rules group, click Form Submit

[image: Perform Custom actions using Rules]

Comment: I have Infopath 2010.  I created the form from a sharepoint list and want it to publish/store to the same sharepoint list (not library - that option is available on infopath).  I'm not sure if I answered everything??

Comment: Replied in Update to my answer

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried it but it should be doable. Change the button option from Submit to Rules and Code. Add rules to the button to first use the data connection to submit via email and then submit via your SharePoint connection and then if you wanted the button to also close have it do that as well.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason, only submitting to a library not a list is an option under the rules option.  The submit button allows me to submit to a list (not a library), I just can't have it email as well....

Comment: I'm using a sharepoint list template on infopath to start the list. I've tried adding both rules to submit email and submit to the list and each time I try running it, it just emails twice in a row and the list never gets updated... I'm using the sharepoint list template on infopath because I need to have batch updates to the list.

Comment: Are you using the OOTB Submit button on the form's toolbar, or did you add a separate button? I would add a separate button and then apply the submit rules to that, and hide the submit from the list form. Its been a while since I looked at 2010. Ill try and jump on tonight.